# List files in a directory using PHP, but skip the first 100 files

Tags: php, list, file, directory, skip

The following code lists the files in the "img" directory and gives the total number of files at the end:

```
$path = 'img/*.*';
$count = 0;
foreach(glob($path) as $filename){
echo basename($filename)."<br>";
$count++;
}
echo "<br>".$count;
```

Now I want to list the files, but skip the first 100 files.

So instead of showing files 1 to 500, I want to see files 101 to 500.

How would I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$a = array_slice(glob($path), 100);` after which $a contains all but the 100 first entries (offset 0 - 99 are removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop, add an if condition to echo the file name only if `$count >= 100`:

```
$path = 'img/*.*';
$count = 0;
foreach(glob($path) as $filename){
    if($count >= 100) echo basename($filename)."<br>";
    $count++;
}
echo "<br>".$count;
```